# Asp .Net Core 3.1 Publish wwwroot folder Email Templates

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a simple application using .net core 3.1 with a very simple ContactUs form. Everything is working fine except Publishing.

I am using Core CLI to publish my project using the following command

```
dotnet build SampleApp.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Local
```

Here is my wwwroot folder:

[image]

When I publish my app except for **templates** folder in **wwwroot** everything is published properly.

Here is my .csproj file:

[image]

My question is how to publish the template folder using CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike ASP.NET MVC 5, during publish in **ASP.NET Core** `.cshtml` view files are compiled to `.dll` file, that's why your **templates** folder containing `.cshtml` files in **wwwroot** folder  are being omitted during publish.

Better move your **EmailTemplates** folder inside **Views** folder in the project. Then everything will work as expected.

Comment: So event the cshtml files in wwwroot folder will also be compiled? and what is the best solution for using email templates? either in wwwroot folder or outside of it?

Comment: If I move the template folder outside wwwroot folder then how to get the path of that template? right now I am using _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath to get the email template path.

Comment: @HaseebKhan Yes! It should be compiled even from wwwroot folder but have to check to be sure. wwwroot folder is not for `.cshtml` files rather `.cshtml` should go under **Views** folder as I said in the answer.

Comment: I have moved the folder outside wwwroot but not in the views folder. Now how to get the path for that specific template for sending email?

Comment: @HaseebKhan Whats wrong to move to under **Views\EmailTemplates** folder. You can get the path easily from here. For outside `Views` folder you have to write full path as `~\EmailTamplates\Test.cshtml`.

Comment: OK. So how to get a proper path from VIew folder? Because I have no controller associated with Email template and I am using a custom mailService to read that template and send

Comment: If you are outside controller then path should be as: `~/Views/EmailTempates/Test.cshtml`

Comment: Got your point. But I believe that must be the hard code path always. Any programmatical way?

Comment: @HaseebKhan Has it worked for you? If it works for you then you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this :

```
First Way -->
```

change `.cshtml` to `.html` for html templates and it will surely work without any other change.

```
Second Way -->

Follow this :
```

1). Make emailtemplates folder in the parent directory.

2).Copy your all email-templates in emailtemplates folder which was created in parent directory.(use .html instead .cshtml for templates)

3). Then use it in any controller like below.

```
Example :
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment iHostingEnvironment)
        {
            _environment = iHostingEnvironment;
        }

        public string LoadTemplate()
        {
            string FilePath = _environment.ContentRootPath;
            var PathWithFolderName = Path.Combine(FilePath, "emailtemplates");

            var file = PathWithFolderName + "\\" + "contact-us.html";

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string html = r.ReadToEnd();
                return html;
            }
        }
    }
```